# Save Canvas Image as image in phones file-system using Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, canvas, phonegap-plugins

I am creating an app that allows the user to take the photo. The photo taken is drawn onto a canvas and tagged with the current date and other user specific information once the editing of the image is done on the canvas, I am able to get the image as DataUri but the app requires the image to be saved to the phones local file-system and get back the path of the saved location on the device file-system. The following is the code for the getting the dataURI:

```
    var canvas = $('#myCanvas')[0];
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();
    var scale = 0.2;
    var imgWidth, imgHeight;
    imageObj.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    imageObj.onload = function() {

        var mpImg = new MegaPixImage(imageObj);

        if (z.globals.deviceType == "iPhone") {

            imgWidth = imageObj.width,
                imgHeight = imageObj.height;
            mpImg.render(document.getElementById('canvas'), { width: imgWidth * scale, height: imgHeight * scale });

        } else {

            canvas.width = 670;
            canvas.height = 500;
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 670, 500);

        }

        var dateTaken = new Date();

        context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";

        context.fillText(toString(dateTaken), 0, 30);

        largeImg.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Is there a way using Phonegap to save the dataURI to device file system and get the filepath back.

I tried the canvas2ImagePlugin.js but it saves the image to gallery but does not return the file path.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to save it as an image file or a file that 64 bit encoded PNG URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, canvas2ImagePlugin returns the URI of the saved file.

It's the argument passed to the success callback refered as "msg" in the doc.

```
window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
        function(msg){
            console.log("Imaged saved to URI : "+msg);
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        },
        document.getElementById('myCanvas')
    );
```

It returns something like this :

`Imaged saved to URI :/storage/sdcard1/Pictures/c2i_1862014144659.png`

Comment: Just a quick note, my answer is unfortunatly true only for android. For IOS, the plugin just returns 'Image saved' in the msg parameter :(

Comment: so after a years, do u find a solution for IOS? Do you mind to share the solution here?

Comment: This issue is disscussed here : https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin/issues/38

Comment: I made a fork to allow to retreive the file name in IOS in the same way as in android. Unfortunatly the pull request hasn't been reviewed because the project owner hasn't much time for this project. You can find the fork here : https://github.com/nicolasgrolleau/Canvas2ImagePlugin

Comment: Look in the pull requests. There are at least three forks that correct the problem in iOS, including mine